# contains() method in ArrayList, Java

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

I am using an ArrayList to save Questions and their answers. The ArrayList is made up of Answer Class which has Question No and an ArrayList of answers_marked as follows:

```
private class Answer {
    private long question_no;
    private ArrayList<long> answer;

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Answer) 
            if (((Answer)o).question_no == this.question_no)
                 return true;
        return false;
    }
}

public ArrayList<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
```

Now, when the user changes his answer I want to look into the answers arraylist and check if the question_no already exists in the answers. If it does then update the answer value for which answer was changed. I am trying to use contains method to check if the question_no already exists, but it always return false. What am I doing wrong here?
Which other data-structure would be best suited for to do this?

I am using answers.contains(new Answer(10,20)) to see if the question_no 10 was already answered.

Comment: Should that be an `ArrayList<Long>`?

Comment: I don't see where you used contains(). but still I would say: Why not use a set. And you have to use brackets with if-clauses. and you should define getters/setters.

Comment: *when the user changes his answer I want to look into the answers arraylist and check if the question_no already exists in the answers* - I've serious concerns about your design..

Comment: With "long" instead of "Long", it shouldn't even compile.

Comment: `contains()` works just fine with your `equals()` implementation, as [you can see here](https://ideone.com/KkmYkY). Your problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Have you considered using `Map<Question, List<Answer>>`?

Comment: is there a way I can get index of where the contains method returns true?

Comment: with contains you ask if the value is in the List. you have to use answers.get(int i) to get what you want

Comment: Its an array list, so i mean get(int i) to get the first occurence of an object you have to use indexOf(Object o)

Comment: @Roadblock: `answers.indexOf(new Answer(10,20))` will give you the index.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a ArrayList you shouldn't do `answers.contains(10)` - this won't work.. 10 is an int and, in your `equals()`, if `o` is not an `Answer` then you are returning `false`.

Rather, try:

```
Answer answer1 = new Answer(1);
Answer answer2 = new Answer(2);

answers.add(answer1);

answers.contains(answer1) ;//= true
answers.contains(answer2) ;//= false
answers.contains(10) ;//= false
```

Comment: The `answers.contains(10)` was apparently some kind of typo, so this answer isn't really valid anymore.

Comment: I am using *answers.contains(new Answer(10,20))* to see if the question_no 10 was already answered